# Perl: is there a way to programmaticly set file test operators? (i.e. -X)

Tags: perl

I often do complex file/directory/symlink tests, and am writing a subroutine to do so.

for example, instead of

`if (-x $file)`

write

```
my $test = '-x';
if ($x $file)
```

and I can vary `$x` to be `-f -r -e` or whatever.

I have read the file testing documentation thoroughly, https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X

and there doesn't appear to be any trick so that this can be done.

I've read `File::Find` https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find but I don't want to write a separate subroutine every time I do a search, which would make the code very ugly and long.

Is there anything or any trick that I've missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `eval`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @tests=qw(r w x o R W X O e z s f d l p S b c t u g k T B M A C);

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    for my $test (@tests) {
        print "-$test $file ";
        my $rv = eval "-${test} \$file";
        $rv = 'undef' unless defined $rv;
        print "$rv\n";
    }
}
```

Running this script on itself may give this output:

```
$ ./perltest.pl perltest.pl
-r perltest.pl 1
-w perltest.pl 1
-x perltest.pl 1
-o perltest.pl 1
-R perltest.pl 1
-W perltest.pl 1
-X perltest.pl 1
-O perltest.pl 1
-e perltest.pl 1
-z perltest.pl
-s perltest.pl 316
-f perltest.pl 1
-d perltest.pl
-l perltest.pl
-p perltest.pl
-S perltest.pl
-b perltest.pl
-c perltest.pl
-t perltest.pl undef
-u perltest.pl
-g perltest.pl
-k perltest.pl
-T perltest.pl 1
-B perltest.pl
-M perltest.pl 1.15740740740741e-05
-A perltest.pl 0
-C perltest.pl 1.15740740740741e-05
```

Comment: `my @tests = split '', 'rwxoRWXOezsfdlpSbctugkTBMAC';`

Comment: @PolarBear Yes, that saves a few characters indeed :-)

Comment: You could use this construction in a subroutine -- then pass into subroutine a string with desired tests.

Comment: @PolarBear Yeah. I'm not sure how OP will use it. I just wanted to show that it's possible to make a generic tester for OP:s `my $test = '-x';
if ($x $file)` case.

Comment: Indeed it is not clear how OP will use test result. May be **Håkon Hægland** approach has some merit based on result of the test to call proper handler subroutine (for example the file was not updated for a while then download most recent copy from internet -- although for this purpose there is a function `mirror` in [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Tiny#mirror)).

Comment: @PolarBear Yes, Håkons answer definitely has some merit. One could also call `stat` and return all the data at once and pick from that, which is what the perl `-X` tests do. I even think perl caches the `stat` internally so that the loop above is probably solved by one `stat` ... if I remember correctly. I haven't used perl on a regular basis in many years...

Comment: @con, I fixed a code injection bug in this answer. If you're using this answer, you should adjust your code similarly.

Comment: @ikegami Many thanks! I think your answer deserves to stay, so I'll upvote it instead of incorperating it in mine.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another approach using a dispatch table:

```
my $file = 'test.txt';
my %ftest = (
    '-x' => sub {-x $_[0]},
    '-f' => sub {-f $_[0]}
);
my $test = '-x';
if ($ftest{$test}->($file)) {
    say "Executable";
}
else {
    say "Not executable";
}
```

Comment: You could even build the dispatch table using eval. `my %ftest = map { $_ => eval "sub { $_ shift }" } qw( -x -f -d -e -z -s );`

Answer (score 4):

[ *This is an improvement on [Ted Lyngmo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160561/589924) and [Håkon Hægland's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160577/589924).* ]

You can use [`eval EXPR`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) to generate code to perform the tests.

Of note, one can take care to avoid perform an expensive `stat` call for every test.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my @tests = split '', 'rwxoRWXOezsfdpSbctugkTBMACl';

my ($qfn) = @ARGV;
   or die("Usage\n");

stat($qfn)
   or die("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n");

for my $test (@tests) {
   my $rv = eval("-$test " . ( $test eq 'l' ? '$qfn' : '_' ));
   say "  -$test: ",  $rv // "[undef]" || 0;
}
```

If multiple files need to be processed, the number of calls to the expensive `eval` can be reduced by using it to create a sub.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my @tests = split '', 'rwxoRWXOezsfdpSbctugkTBMACl';
my %tests =
   map { $_ => eval("sub { -$_ shift }") }
      @tests;

for my $qfn (@ARGV) {
   stat($qfn)
      or warn("Can't stat \"$qfn\": $!\n"), next;

   say "$qfn:";
   for my $test (@tests) {
      my $rv = $tests{$test}->( $test eq 'l' ? $qfn : *_ );
      say "  -$test: ",  $rv // "[undef]" || 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution! it usually runs faster than repeated evals. What is the meaning of `_*`? and how does the test return `$l`?

Comment: Re "*What is the meaning of `_*`*"? `-f _`  is short for `-f *_`. You can't use just `_` elsewhere in the code, though, so I had to use `*_`. As for what `-f _` means, it's pretty clear in the [docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X). (Search for the word "underline")

Comment: Re "*how does the test return `$l`?*", I don't understand this question. For starters, `$l` doesn't appear anywhere in the code.